# Imagemagick buildpack for Heroku-18 stack

Tags: heroku, stack, imagemagick

I am upgrading my Heroku tech stack to Heroku-18 from heroku-16. I am getting error while deploying beacause of un supported Imagemagic build pack for Heroku-18. Is there any option to use another Imagemagic version that supports in Heroku-18 stack.thanks in advance.

Comment: There are two versions of ImageMagick, 6.x.x.x and 7.x.x.x. Perhaps you installed 7 and your Heroku only supports 6.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Heroku 18 already comes with Imagemagick, so you no longer need the separate buildpack.